# SQL Server/SSIS - Deleting files from Directory

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got list of files which were not imported during the SSIS Package. I want to delete the files which were imported from the ROOT DIRECTORY and that will leave it with missing files only. So when I start the package, only missing files will be there in directory.

So what I need is - how to delete files from C: Drive directory from SQL Server which were imported so that I can skip them now.

Urgent help required

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but here's how you delete files from SQL Server.

```
-- Enable xp_cmdshell
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
go
reconfigure
go

-- Delete a file
exec xp_cmdshell 'del c:\yourfile.txt'
go
```